Removing *.desktop application and also removing dependencies
Recently I uninstalled an application via apt but the application came with a GUI which was still on the GNOME menu. I had to remove this from "/usr/share/applications" but before I did I could launch the application and it still worked without an issue. Before I finally deleted it I noticed that this .desktop file was only 433 bytes so what are the odds it should be that small and still work unless that’s not the real application and just something else.
I researched a bit and found that these are just launchers to the actual application so I didn’t really delete the application which means that it is still somewhere on my disk. This is the GUI application that came with the console application.
Where do I go from here? How can I get rid of it?

What is the actual name of the .desktop file, and what is the name of the package that you removed with apt?

hplip, hp-device-manager. I have done this with other packages too but I just got curious this time.

Well, hplip.desktop is provided by the hplip-gui package. See for example How do I find the package that provides a file?

What gives!? Who would have known that "hplip-gui" is another package installed with "hplip"? apt probably told me but I didn’t read it through. So uninstalling this package should do the trick then? Say I hadn’t removed the ".desktop" file manually, would it be gone automatically? If so then this is not a proper question.

In your question, you are not giving any clue about which application it concerns. Specific help thus is not possible, but you may be looking for general insight only.
Any package/application installed using APT can also be removed using APT. In general, any application installed using a package manager can also be removed using that. Ubuntu has two systems, the APT system en the Snap system. Both are managed in the same way through the Ubuntu App Center. If instead you use the command line, the appropriate tools (apt and snap) have to be used for applications installed using the respective package managers.
If a launcher —these correspond with a .desktop file— remains in the application overview, then the executable is also still on your system. That is because a launcher for which the corresponding executable is not anymore on the system, will not appear in the menu at all.
Thus, just double check. Your previous effort to remove the application did not succeed.
